# Check if selected date is greater than yesterday Typescript + React, momentjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date, validation, momentjs

how can i check if date is greater than yesterday using typescript and momentjs?

Im also using validator, example:

```
isPin: {
    validator: (value: string) => value.length <= 6 && value.length >= 4,
    message: 'Please enter a pin with 4 to 6 numbers'
},
```

I would like to use validator with the date too.

I have tried:

```
isGreaterThanYesterday: {
    validator: (value: string) => value.toString() > moment().toString(),
    message: 'The date must be greater than yesterday'
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **value** is a valid date string of format 'YYYY-MM-DD', you can perform the following operation:

```
isGreaterThanYesterday: {
    validator: (value: string):boolean => moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').isAfter(moment().subtract(1, 'days') ,
    message: 'The date must be greater than yesterday'
}
```

Note that you do not need toString on value since type is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide date format but I will assume it is 'YYYY-MM-DD', as it is standard html format. So, if you want to check if date is strictly greater than yesterday, you can do it like this (check if date is greater or equal today's date):

```
value >= moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If you want to check if date is greater or equal than yesterday, you can do it like this:

```
value >= moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: You are comparing 2 strings here, i dont think this works

Comment: actually it works, it first compares years, then months, and then days which is how date comparison works

Comment: It works for this specific date format, the second you change the format you break the comparison.